# Mule call to external system

Tags: mule

I have a scenario where I am inserting the data from FTP file into various systems.

Depending on success or failure, the entry should be made in another system using SOAP call. The other system is maintained entirely for statistical purpose.

My approach was to have two flow-refs , one in case of success and other in exception strategy, which will call the flow making SOAP call to other system.

Is this the right approach? If not, I would like to know if there is any functionality in Mule which can detect end of the process(running in the background) and call a flow which will internally call the SOAP web service.

Thanks,

Varada

Answer (score 0):

Having separate flows for different tasks is absolutely a good idea. A recommendation/suggestion from my end is to configure these two flows as private flows with asynchronous processingStrategy. You can rather configure these two flows as sub-flows with vm inbound endpoint. This approach, however, is not recommended to your requirement, as vm endpoints serialize/de-serialize the message, which you don't need, of course.